# How do I make Babel require the Babel-compiled Files?

Tags: babeljs

If I have two files, let's call them A.js and B.js:

```
/src/A.js
/src/B/B.js
```

A.js uses B.js via ES6 module syntax:

```
import B from './B/B.js';
```

and B.js imports other stuff such as:

```
import http from 'http';
```

I'm using Babel to convert the module syntax to `require` (CommonJS) syntax, and I can run it successfully by doing:

```
node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js src > compiled.js
```

However, there's a problem: when I try to run the resulting `compiled.js` I get:

```
/src/b/B.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import http from 'http';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

The part of the stack trace that comes from `compiled.js` points to this line:

```
var _B = require('./src/b/B')
```

Although the actual import causing the problem comes from B.js:

```
import http from 'http';
```

It seems like the original B.js is being required-in, because the copy of B.js's code inside compiled.js doesn't have an `import`, but I don't understand why that version isn't being used.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You usually transform a whole directory so that relative paths between the files continue to work. Why are you compiling files individually and rename them?

Comment: Because I'm a dummy who is used to Webpack and has never had to compile Babel manually before.  I'll try running it on my directory instead, thanks!

Comment: That didn't work.  It converts the `import` in A.js into a `require`, but leaves B.js as a separate file (with an import).  I had hoped it would put both A.js and B.js in to compiled.js, but no such luck.

Comment: That's not possible. If you run `babel src --out-dir lib` then all files in `src` will be compiled. Have a look at https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/, maybe that helps. *edit:* Maybe you misunderstand me or I am misunderstanding you. If you want to create a single file then you can run `babel src --out-file script-compiled.js`.

Comment: Ok, I double-checked and B.js is there in compiled.js ... but it's not helping.  Despite compiled.js having both A and B, when I run `nodejs compiled.js` I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" pointing to a line in compiled.js that looks like `var _B = require('./src/B');` (`src` being the parent folder of A.js and B.js).  But I can see the code for B.js later on in the file, so I can't understand why Babel doesn't use it ...

Comment: Oh I guess the issue is that converting to CommonJS modules *and* concatenating the files doesn't work well together. Babel doesn't provide a module loader implementation. So any `require()` that is inside the concatenated file will be resolved normally by Node. What is ultimate goal? If you want a module bundler then you should use one. If not, transpiling all files into a new directory (not concatenating them into a single file), i.e. ` babel src --out-dir lib` should work just fine?

Comment: It sounds like maybe I do need Webpack after all (despite being in a NodeJS environment).  I'll try outputting to a directory instead of a file first though and see if that works.  Thanks.

Comment: You only need to a module bundler if you want to bundle all files into a single file. If you just want to compile the code to be used in node use `babel src --out-dir lib` and load your entry file from `lib/`. See https://github.com/reactjs/react-docgen/blob/93998a75d736159b88d712720de04cf88ff0b075/package.json as an example.

Comment: That worked!  Well sort of; I still have some issue with it not finding a library, but that can wait until tomorrow :)  Thanks for all the help, and if you feel inclined to summarize all that in an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to rename any imports. Instead of compiling individual files, compile your whole source folder. This will preserve relative imports.

If your have

```
src/
  A.js
  B.js
```

and run `babel src --out-dir lib`, you will get

```
lib/
  A.js
  B.js
src/
  A.js
  B.js
```

The `lib/` folder contains the compiled files. Now you can execute the compiled code via `node lib/A.js` and it should work as expected.